# Why do only some of my javascript functions work

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, forms

I am using javascript and ajax to validate a register form at the moment the function restrict(elem) and the function checkusername() seem to be working, the ajax is passing checkusername variable to PHP and this checks if the username exists and displays a message to me saying username taken or available but no other fields get validated, this is my javascript

javascript validation clientside b4 going to php

```
function restrict(elem) {
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if (elem === "email") {
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if (elem === "username") {
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    } else if (elem === "mobileNumber") {
        rx = /[0-9]/g;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}

function emptyElement(x) {
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}

function checkusername() {
    var u = _("username").value;
    if (u !== "") {
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        };
        ajax.send("usernamecheck=" + u);
    }
}

function signup() {
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var m = _("mobileNumber").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var ci = _("city").value;
    var pc = _("postcode").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var d = _("dateOfBirth").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if (u === "" || e === "" || p1 === "" || p2 === "" || c === "" || g === "" || m === "" || ci === "" || pc === "" || d === "") {
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out required fields";
    } else if (p1 !== p2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if (m !== 11 && !IsNumeric(m)) {
        status.innerHTML = "Please enter valid mobile number";
    } else if (d === "dd/mm/yyyy") {
        status.innerHTML = "Please enter your date of birth";

    } else {
        //ajax to send form data to php
        //hides sign button
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        //wait until php verifies data
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
                //if sign not succesful unhide button
                if (ajax.responseText !== "signup_success") {
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK " + u + ", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>" + e + "</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        };
        ajax.send("u=" + u + "&e=" + e + "&p=" + p1 + "&c=" + c + "&g=" + g + "&ci" + ci + "&m" + m + "&pc" + pc + "&d" + d);
    }
}
```

and here is my form

```
  <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
     <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
     <div>First name:</div> 
     <input id="firstName" type="text"  /><br />
     <div>Last name:</div> 
     <input id="lastName" type="text"   /><br />
     <div>Mobile number*:</div>
     <input name="mobileNumber" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('mobileNumber')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>City:</div>
    <input id="city" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Postcode:</div>
    <input id="postcode" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <div>Relationship Status*:</div>
    <select id="relationshipStatus" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
        <option value="Taken">Taken</option>            
                </select>
    <div>Date of Birth*:</div>
    <input id="dateOfBirth" type="date" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
```

Comment: [It's a good idea to clean up your code before posting so that people can read it.](http://jsbeautifier.org)

Comment: Sorry about the messy code, I want the signup() function to be called when the user attempts submit the form and this will check if the fields mentioned in the signup() function are either empty or that pass1 matches pass2 etc

Answer (score 1):

Your validation regular expressions won't do what you want:

```
function restrict(elem) {
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if (elem === "email") {
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if (elem === "username") {
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    } else if (elem === "mobileNumber") {
        rx = /[0-9]/g;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
```

Your expression are set up so that they'll pass validation if any single character in the field value matches the character range.  You can stipulate that an entire string consist of characters from a particular range like this:

```
rx = /^[a-z0-9]*$/;
```

Comment: What does the *$ mean I thought if you put /g after the array this makes it global and checks it against every character in the field?

Comment: @JWayne93 no, that's not what the "g" flag does. The `^` and the `$` match the beginning and  the end of the string. The "g" flag is mostly for doing replacements.

Comment: Oh ok thanks that makes sense I was looking at a replacement example, I am still not sure why the signup() function in my javascript does not execute, do you have any clues?

Comment: I can't tell from looking at it; have you tried adding some `console.log()` calls to it so that you can see what's happening? Have you noticed errors in the browser console?

Comment: Ah I understand now thanks, underneath tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, ""); it says UnCaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null  and also the same message underneath $var m = _("mobileNumber").value;